# Why is input resistance parallel with the base of BJT?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential, input-impedance, single-ended

I'm solving for the third stage. The resistance looking into the base of Q7 is taken between its base terminal and ground as follows during small signal analysis for single end gain of Second Stage Amplifier. Can some elaborate on why the Input Resistance of Q7 taken like this.

[image: Complete Circuit for DC Analysis]

[image: Small Signal Circuit for Single Ended Gain of Second Stage]

Comment: Are you asking why the input resistance of T7 is defined between base and ground? Answer: Because the positive DC voltage source (15V) has (asumed) zero internal resistance to ground.

Comment: Shouldn't it be in series? If we consider the T-model of BJT we get the input resistance that is in series with the source.

Comment: Yes, of course! You can verify this by a simple visual inspection without using any small-signal equivalent diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Ri3 is how Q5 sees Q7 and what's connected to it. Ri3 the other end grounded presents for Q5 all what's to the right from Q5 when one calculates only how weak AC components of voltages and currents behave.

As already said in a comment the DC supply is considered as zero ohm wire when one calculates  AC behaviour. DC source has certain constant voltage, no current variations change it, so its like a wire for AC.